# Citation is undefined

Tags: latexmk

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
  \begin{center}
   \Large\textbf{A Review of Introduction: Ethnicity, Identity and Music}\\
   \Large\textit{T. Burgess}
 \end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
\end{titlepage}
\paragraph{}
Martin Stokes is an ethnomusicologist teaching/researching ethnomusicology and anthropology of music\cite{Stokes2019}.
\bibliographystyle{chicagoa} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

and a `Bibliography.bib` in the same directory:

```
@article{Stokes2019,
title = {Ethnicity, Identity and Music},
volume = {155},
issn = {0012-8252},
shorttitle = {Theoretical, contemporary observational},
url = {https://www.kcl.ac.uk/people/professor-martin-stokes},
doi = {10.1016/j.earscirev.2016.01.010},
urldate = {2019-01-05},
journal = {Some Journal},
author = {Stokes},
month = apr,
year = {2019},
keywords = {Ethnomusicology, Music},
pages = {1--27},
}
```

But I get `Citation 'Stokes2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 13`
in the following log:

```
Output written on /home/tim/Documents/MUSI105/Assn1.pdf (2 pages, 61073 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /home/tim/Documents/MUSI105/Assn1.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /home/tim/Documents/MUSI105/Assn1.log.
'Assn1.fls' and '/home/tim/Documents/MUSI105/Assn1.fls' are identical (not copied) at /usr/bin/latexmk line 7510.
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'Assn1.bbl'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Assn1.pdf'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Assn1.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `Stokes2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 13
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [Bibliography.bib]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to '/home/tim/Documents/MUSI105/Assn1.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

It's not evident to me how the Bibliography is not getting found..

Comment: I’ve removed it. That was an incorrect tag

Comment: How is this related to the `latexmk` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `\usepackage{natbib}` in order to use the `chicagoa` bib style.